# How to specify a general formula for this bunch of for-loops to reduce code?

Tags: java, for-loop

There is a chess grid of 11x11. Each grid has a button with a coordinate. The upper-left-most side has a coordinate of (0,0) and the lower-right-most side has a coordinate of (11,11). These for-loops try to map a valid collection of paths for the Rook piece in Cardinal directions (South, East, etc...) . As you may guess, These for-loops generally function like this:

1. get coordinates of the current button in the grid.
2. Add these coordinates to validCoordinates.
3. if there is an enemy on the next grid, add the enemy's coordinates too.

If you noticed, all of these for-loops are basically the same just that the statements of the for-loops and its variables are slightly different but I can't think of a way to specify a general for-loop for those for-loops.

`originalrow is the current row coordinate of the Rook piece`

`originalcol is the current column coordinate of the Rook piece`

```
      for(int r=originalrow+1;buttons[r][originalcol]!=null&&buttons[r][originalcol].getIcon()!=null;r++){
            //check south
            Integer coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[r][originalcol]);
            validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
            if(buttons[r+1][originalcol].getIcon()!=null){//add valid coordinate also to eat enemy
                if(buttons[r+1][originalcol].getIcon().toString().charAt(0)==enemyColor){
//An enemy/friendly exists when .getIcon() returns true. In order to differentiate enemy/friendly, 
//each Icon has a description "w" for white or "b" for black at .charAt(0)
                    coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[r+1][originalcol]);
                    validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int r=originalrow-1;buttons[r][originalcol]!=null&&buttons[r][originalcol].getIcon()!=null;r--){
            //check north
            Integer coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[r][originalcol]);
            validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
            if(buttons[r-1][originalcol].getIcon()!=null){//add valid coordinate also to eat enemy
                if(buttons[r-1][originalcol].getIcon().toString().charAt(0)==enemyColor){
                    coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[r-1][originalcol]);
                    validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int c=originalcol-1;buttons[originalrow][c]!=null&&buttons[originalrow][c].getIcon()!=null;r--){
            //check west
            Integer coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[originalrow][c]);
            validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
            if(buttons[originalrow][c-1].getIcon()!=null){//add valid coordinate also to eat enemy
                if(buttons[originalrow][c-1].getIcon().toString().charAt(0)==enemyColor){
                    coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[originalrow][c-1]);
                    validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int c=originalcol+1;buttons[originalrow][c]!=null||buttons[originalrow][c].getIcon()!=null;r++){
            //check east
            Integer coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[originalrow][c]);
            validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
            if(buttons[originalrow][c+1].getIcon()!=null){//add valid coordinate also to eat enemy
                if(buttons[originalrow][c+1].getIcon().toString().charAt(0)==enemyColor){
                    coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[originalrow][c+1]);
                    validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
                }
            }
        }
```

In C, I could easily use the #define directive to create a variable that can hold different kind of statement of codes but with Java, it doesn't seem to have that.

Comment: @Jarrod did u thumbs down my question? If so, does a small mistake like tagging in the title really require a thumbs down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to generalize your algorithm in a way like this:

```
int[] dx = {-1,1,0,0};
int[] dy = {0,0,-1,1};

for (int direction = 0; direction < 4; direction++) {
    int r = originalrow + dx[direction];
    int c = originalcol + dy[direction];

    while (buttons[r][c] != null && buttons[r][c].getIcon() != null) {
        Integer coordinate[] = getButtonCoord(buttons[r][c]);
        validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
        r += dx[direction];
        c += dy[direction];
        if (buttons[r][c].getIcon() != null) {// add valid coordinate
                                                // also to eat enemy
            if (buttons[r][c].getIcon().toString().charAt(0) == enemyColor) {
                validCoordinates.add(coordinate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I did not execute this code as I don't have all the necessary classes/methods defined. Thus I cannot guarantee that it works, but you can get an idea. Here we have a possible directions coded in `dx`/`dy` arrays. By the way you can easily support diagonals now simply adding more entries into `dx`/`dy`:

```
int[] dx = {-1,1,0,0,1,1,-1,-1};
int[] dy = {0,0,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1};
```

Also it might be reasonable to introduce a `Point` type.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give u a feedback soon.